# Adding keys to dicts within a list, from values in a list

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, key

How can I add keys to a dict within a list, if the dict contains a certain key, from values in another list?

I have a list of dicts. Those dicts either contain only one key ('review'), or two keys ('review' and 'response'). When the dict contains the key 'response', I want to add two keys, with values from two lists.

```
data = [{'response': 'This is a response',
         'review': 'This is a review'},
        {'review': 'This is only a review'},
        {'response': 'This is also a response',
         'review': 'This is also a review'}]
date = ['4 days ago',
        '3 days ago']
responder = ['Manager',
             'Customer service']
```

I have tried the following, but since for each dict that contains the key 'response' I only want to add 1 from the values from each lists, I am not sure how to do this.

```
for d in data:
    if 'response' in d:
        for i in date:
            d['date'] = i
        for i in responder:
            d['responder'] = i
```

The output shows me that it of course only adds the last values of the lists since I'm looping over the lists. How can I fix this?

```
[{'date': '3 days ago',
  'responder': 'Customer service',
  'response': 'This is a response',
  'review': 'This is a review'},
 {'review': 'This is only a review'},
 {'date': '3 days ago',
  'responder': 'Customer service',
  'response': 'This is also a response',
  'review': 'This is also a review'}]
```

Comment: How do you decide which item from `date` and `responder` should be added as value to a dictionary?

Comment: The responses, dates and responders were scraped and parsed at the same time, so the first review with a response belongs to the first date and the first responder.

Comment: would you please provide expected output !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an iterator for your date and responder lists and then call `next()` in your if statement to take the next item from the list

```
data = [{'response': 'This is a response', 
         'review': 'This is a review'}, 

        {'review': 'This is only a review'}, 

        {'response': 'This is also a response', 
         'review': 'This is also a review'}]

date = ['4 days ago', '3 days ago']
responder = ['Manager', 'Customer service']

d_iter = iter(date)
r_iter = iter(responder)

for d in data:
    if 'response' in d:
        d['date'] = next(d_iter)
        d['responder'] = next(r_iter)

print(data)
>> [
{'date': '4 days ago', 
 'review': 'This is a review', 
 'responder': 'Manager', 
 'response': 'This is a response'},  

{'review': 'This is only a review'}, 

{'date': '3 days ago', 
 'review': 'This is also a review', 
 'responder': 'Customer service', 
 'response': 'This is also a response'}
]
```

Comment: Nice work. I solved this using generators, but the `iter` and `next` combination is much more clean than `for` loops with breaks.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, but be careful, because of number of `response` on your list should be equals to length your lists:

```
d_r = zip(date, responder)

for d in data:
    if 'response' in d:
            d['date'], d['responder'] = next(d_r)
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying add two entries with Date as key and values are different. In dictionary you cant have duplicate keys. That's why after the for loop Dictionary is updated with only one Date key entry and only one responder entry